# Optimization problem with variables in the subscript

Tags: optimization, game-theory

I want to solve a optimization problem, which mimics the actions between a seller and several buyers. A seller has several goods, 1, 2, ... J, with prices $p_j$ and quantity $q_j$. A buyer can only buy one merchandise and he wants to buy the merchandise which he considers to be the best among all of them. 
If we use variable $x_{ij}=1$ to indicate whether buyer i wants to buy merchandise j, and $x_{ij}=0$ otherwise. The strategy for buyer i is simple:

$j^* = arg~max~(b_j-p_j)$, if $max_j~(b_j-p_j) \geq 0$, where $b_j$ is the evaluation of product $j$.

However, the seller wants to maximize his revenue by solving:

max $\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}p_j$

subject to: $\sum_i x_{ij} \leq q_j$

Suppose that the seller doesn't know $b_j$ of each buyer. How can the seller dynamically adjust the price $p_j$ so that his total revenue can be maximized?

Comment: An alternate way to view the buyers' strategy is that they maximize the sum over j of (b_j - p_j) * x_ij. And they have constraints sum x_ij <=1 and each x_ij >= 0.  Maybe this approach will help as you are no longer considering the j's to be the variable.